# How to grey out part of a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a site where students can see statistics about professors.

Here is the code of the form

```
<?php

$pageName = "statisitcsForm.php";
$pageTitle = "Statistics Form";
include("../inc/config.php");
require(SITE_ROOT . "inc/db.php");
include(SITE_ROOT . "inc/header.php");


try {
    $results = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM professors
    ORDER BY professorLastName");

    $results2 = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM majors
    ORDER BY majorID");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
    exit;
}

$professors = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$majors = $results2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



?>


    <div id="statisticsFormBody">

        <form action="../php/statistics.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-div">
                <h3><label for="major"> First Select Major: </label> <br></h3>
                <select class="form-input" id="major" name="major">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($majors as $major) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $major['majorID']; ?>"> <?php echo $major['majorName'] ?> </option>
                    <?php
                    } ?>

                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-div">
                <h3><label for="prof"> Then Select Professor: </label> <br></h3>
                <select class="form-input" id="prof" name="prof">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($professors as $prof) { ?>
                        <option
                            value="<?php echo $prof['professorID']; ?>"> <?php echo $prof['professorLastName'] . ' ' . $prof['professorFirstName'] ?> </option>
                    <?php
                    } ?>

                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-div">
                <input type="submit" class="form-btn" id="Go" name="Go" value="Go">
                <button type="reset" class="form-btn"> Clear</button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>


<?php include SITE_ROOT . "inc/footer.php"; ?>
```

How do I get the second select to show only professors from the `majorID` that the user chooses in the first select?

`professor.majorID` references majors.majorID in database.

Perhaps a solution using jquery (AJAX)?

Comment: First things first..Start by restructuring your database. You need to have a foreign key in your `professors` table that will connect professors to `majors`..

Comment: There is one. Both tables have majorID.
My question is related to how I will grey out the <select> and fill it with a query like: "SELECT * FROM professors WHERE majorID= theMajorThatStudentChose"

Comment: You need ajax for your database operations (i.e. filtering)

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment with no effort attempted to solve it

Comment: Guys trust me much effort has been put into this site. I just am a noob in javascript and I needed some guidance on the matter.

Comment: If *"Any Suggestions?"* is your question, I'd argue this should be closed since it's opinion based and far too broad.  Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tour for an overview of the types of questions that are appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: @padawanTony, you can get guidance here far more effectively if you can demonstrate some code you've tried and ask specific questions about how to get it working the way you'd like.

Comment: And what should my question be like? I clearly state: "I want the 'Choose Professor' option to be greyed out until the student selects a major.

And I also want the professors that will appear in the 'Select Professor' to be of the
 major that the student has chosen." 
How much more specific?

Comment: @billynoah I understand what you're saying. I just did not want to go into detail because it was not relevant. All I wanted was someone to mention "ajax" (which I did not know it exists) or to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you visit the tour link I posted?  If you did you might have read something like this: *Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.*.

Or this: *Don't ask ... questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)*

Comment: Alright. From now on I will show my work. So let me rephrase my question.

Comment: Hi Tony. As per my two edits, code fomatting is not appropriate for ordinary paragraph text. It is used for code and console input/output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for improving your question.  One approach you could take is to add a class to each professor option which indicates which majorID it's associated with like this:

```
<div class="form-div">
    <h3><label for="prof"> Then Select Professor: </label> <br></h3>
    <select class="form-input" id="prof" name="prof">
        <?php foreach ($professors as $prof) { ?>
            <option class="major-<?php echo $prof['majorID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $prof['professorID']; ?>"> <?php echo $prof['professorLastName'] . ' ' . $prof['professorFirstName'] ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then use jQuery to bind a javascript `change` event to the first select and add/remove options as needed:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        profOptions = $("#prof option"); // store all options as a jQuery object
        $("#major").trigger("change"); // trigger change on first select
    });
    $("#major").on("change", function() { // this event will fire anytime first select is changed
        var majorID = this.value; // get value of first select
        $("#prof option").remove(); // remove all professor options
        profOptions.each( function() { // iterate through options
            if ($(this).hasClass("major-" + majorID)) { // check if option has matching classname
                $("#prof").append($(this)); // append option to second select
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice idea. I cannot make it work however. Probably I am putting sth in the wrong place. Told you I'm a noob in jquery!
I'll study my ajax and come back to you once I make it work

Comment: You probably don't need ajax for this... it's a bit much for such scenario imo

Comment: Also, I updated my answer since you'd need to initially hide all professor options on page load.  You could also do it with jQuery - I used inline CSS here.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Also note you have an extra `?>` in the code you posted.  Get rid of that and paste the script I've given you at the bottom of the main `<div>` and it should work.  And make sure you are including jQuery library 1.8+ on your page.

Comment: I'm using jquery-2.1.3.js

Still doesn't work.
take a look if you want: http://ashoka.students.acg.edu/Coursework/test/statisticsForm.php

Comment: Looks like it works to me.  Just that since you have no default option you need to trigger a change event on page load.  I've updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: You only have options for first majorID so if you change it and change it back you'll see the options appear.

Comment: yes I only have option for the first major. But still it displays these options in the other majors, whereas it shouldn't display anything for the other majors. But I can see that you're really close.

Comment: seems to be a chrome issue.. works in firefox.  I'll update the answer in a sec.  try it in firefox in the meantime.

Comment: The update removes the first professor from the list.

Try to select another major and then go back to the first major again. The first professor has dissappeared

Comment: You need to remove `style="display: none" ` from the options html.

Comment: I hope I get an A+ on this assignment :-)

Comment: It works!
I don't know about the A+ but you certainly get a thank you from me :)

Comment: Of course, this only works because we have already brought all the data from the database. 
If we needed to make a query to the database only for the professors who have the majorID that the user selects, we would need to use AJAX.

Comment: Correct.  And in either case there is a jQuery plug-in which may be of interest and can also handle AJAX: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

[Example JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lkph6wd/)

```
<body>
<form>
    <select id="major">
        <option>Choose Major</option>
        <option>Major1</option>
        <option>Major2</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select id="profs" disabled>
        <option>Choose Prof</option>
        <option>Prof1</option>
        <option>Prof2</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>

$('#major').on('change', function(){
if($('#major')[0].selectedIndex != 0){
    $('#profs').prop("disabled", false);
} else {
    $('#profs').prop("disabled", true);
}});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

What I want is to fill the 2nd select based on the major that the user picked in the 1st select.

For example, if user picked Major2 then he will see only the Professors of Major2 in the 2nd select.

Comment: send a $.get / $.ajax to your server with the selected option as argument

Comment: You can use `if($(this)[0].selectedIndex != 0){` as better code . No need  to duplicate selector.
`

Comment: I, know but thanks for giving the hint. Just had a typo before in the fiddle and didn't worked, changed it to the selector and then back, but didn't saved :)

Answer (score 0):

use ajax methods from jQuery to get list of professors, and set/unset "disabled" attribute of  element in callback-function of ajax-query.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into it now.